# Disable Printing "Markup" permanently in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

When working on MS Word 2016 Documents I have to review and change each document several times and also keep a record of changes. The "Track Changes" option in MS Word is very useful for this purpose. But whenever I print the document it also prints the tracked changes. There is an option to prevent printing of markup each time when a document is printed but I need to disable this permanently.

**It there a way to disable printing of markup permanently in MS Word 2016?**

Comment: For Word 2010, this link refers to creating an AutoOpen macro in normal.dotm, so that every time a document is opened the setting is changed.  I don't have Word 2016 so don't know if same will work there but might be worth a try.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f1e4529-386c-45e9-b338-3fe7d674fd01/change-default-to-final-tracking-in-word-2010?forum=word

Answer (score 2):

A practical solution should be very simple:

Before printing, tell Word to not display on screen the changes

> Menu: Review --> Tracking --> Final  [not: "Final - Show Markup"]

Now when printing, only what you see on screen will be printed; "markup" (e.g. red coloured new text, or red coloured stroke-out text) will not appear in print.

I would suppose you know that anyway.

You may find it annoying to each time go through the menu items to set that setting. For that purpuse I use the following minimalistic VBA procedure ("macro"):

```
Sub TrackChangesViewToggler()

   ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions

End Sub
```

This toggles the seeting in question. Each time run, the setting changes (on-off-on-off...) I trigger this via keyboard shortcut (*AltGr v* in my case, but you can assign whatever you want).

If you need this only and solely for printing, I recommend: make yourself a VBA procedure that first sets that setting, then sends the document to your printer. You can easily record such a procedure without knowing too much about VBA programming.